# Quesition on C++ polymorphism usage

Tags: c++, polymorphism

```
#include<iostream>

class base{
  public:
  virtual void run(){};
  protected:
  ~base(){std::cout<<"destructor for base"<<std::endl;};
};

class derived : public base {
   public:
   void run(){};
   ~derived(){std::cout<<"destructor for derived"<<std::endl;};
};

void get_type ( std::shared_ptr<base> b ){
    b.reset ( new derived );
    std::cout<<"end of get_type"<<std::endl;
}

int main(){
  std::shared_ptr<base> b;
  get_type ( b ) ;
  std::cout<<"out of get_type"<<std::endl;
  b->run();
}
```

It compiles okay but I got segmentation fault. I looked into what's happening and the output is

end of get_type
destructor for derived
destructor for base
out of get_type
Segmentation fault: 11

It goes into get_type and allocates its type. However, beyond this function scope it automatically destructs the type again. Then, since it cannot find b->run(), it gives seg fault. Anyone knows how to make it work? I can't find similar questions. Sorry if it is possible duplication.

Comment: You forgot to make `base::~base()` virtual

Comment: Compile with all warnings on, and you should have received a warning exactly about what @AntonSavin has stated.

Comment: That does not solve it. I am also using -g -Wall -std=c++11 -pedantic -Wextra -Wcast-align -Wcast-qual -Wctor-dtor-privacy -Wdisabled-optimization -Wformat=2 -Winit-self -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wold-style-cast -Woverloaded-virtual -Wredundant-decls -Wshadow -Wsign-conversion -Wsign-promo -Wstrict-overflow=5 -Wswitch-default -Wundef -Werror -Wno-unused for the flag. No warning message is printed out.

Comment: You have a pointer, but you have not initialized it.  You did not make your pointer point to something.

Comment: I made it point to derived in get_type function. I expect to have the side effect of this in main. Is this impossible?

Comment: I suggest using a debugger and placing a breakpoint at the last statement in `main`.  Check the contents of `b` before stepping into the `run` method.

Comment: @user3089810: it's totally possible, but your code doesn't have that particular side-effect.

Answer (score 3):

Your `get_type()` function receives a **copy** of the shared_ptr defined in your `main` function. It then assigns a value to this copy and returns. When leaving the `get_type` function, the copy deallocates its pointer as is normal. Then in your `main` function, the initial shared_ptr is still unassigned and obviously you get a segmenation fault when trying to dereference it to call the `run`method.

For your algorithm to work you should ask a non-const reference to the shared_ptr in the `get_type` function.

**PS:** As others pointed out, you **MUST** make the destructor of your base class virtual.

Comment: I tried passing by reference, and it worked fine. Thanks for these.

Comment: You __SHOULD__ make the destructor of the base class virtual, but it's not strictly necessary for `std::shared_ptr`, only for virtually everything else.